# tf.while_loop - ValueError: The two structures don't have the same number of elements

Tags: python, tensorflow, while-loop

I'm trying to do the following in Tensorflow -

```
import tensorflow as tf

graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():

    i = tf.Variable(0)
    sol = tf.Variable(0)

    def cond(i, sol):
        return tf.less(i, 2)
    def body(i, sol):
        i = tf.add(i, 1)
        sol = tf.add(sol, 1)
    tf.while_loop(cond, body, [i, sol])

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

    result = session.run(sol, feed_dict={})
    print result
```

The error that I get is shown in the image below.
[image]

I'm unable to understand what the two 'structures' are in the error message. I want to ultimately make a 'tf.while_loop' with the 'condition' based on the value of a tf.Placeholder ('i' in the code above).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `return` statement to `body` function:

```py
def body(i, sol):
    i = tf.add(i, 1)
    sol = tf.add(sol, 1)
    return [i, sol]
```

But I think you should also change your code to something like

```py
graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():
    i = tf.Variable(0)
    sol = tf.Variable(0)

    def cond(i, sol):
        return tf.less(i, 2)

    def body(i, sol):
        i = tf.add(i, 1)
        sol = tf.add(sol, 1)
        return [i, sol]

    result = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [i, sol])

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    result = session.run(result, feed_dict={})
    print(result[1])
```

because `tf.while_loop()` is only node in graph, which you should run, else you will not get any results.